# Invalid Argument: null - AWS S3 putObject

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload an image to an S3 Storage, but I am getting the following error:

```
2021-11-12T15:31:25.052Z    66de02a8-091c-4daf-9987-cf3a9f8d827d    INFO    InvalidArgument: null
    at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:699:35)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)
    at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:690:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18) {
  code: 'InvalidArgument',
  region: null,
  time: 2021-11-12T15:31:25.051Z,
  requestId: 'F7F5RRA3WBXPMXBV',
  extendedRequestId: 'rJ8Xv5AFhU0YJkm7hvorAPYX29IzxSRppKWbVOkKnm9x7dJ0O39PtCIHv6G1fyybENfGyLNW/9w=',
  cfId: undefined,
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 63.286937336271485
}
```

I tried everything I found but without success.

The code: First I get an image from a bucket, this is working...

```js
try {
    const params = {
        Bucket: srcBucket,
        Key: srcKey,
    };
    file = await s3.getObject(params).promise();
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return;
}
```

But when I try to upload that image to another bucket I get the error

```js
try {
    const destinationBucketParams = {
        Bucket: "my-bucket-2",
        Key: "resized-00021113-94b7-4fdc-8d4b-0a5dea67daa0",
        Body: file.Body,
        ACL: "pulic-read",
        ContentType: "image/jpeg"
    };
    await s3.putObject(destinationBucketParams).promise();
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return;
}
```

The configuration:

```js
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
    
const s3 = new AWS.S3({region: "sa-east-1"});
```

Comment: You have a typo in `pulic-read`, it should be `public-read`

Comment: It seems that the region parameter is null.

Comment: @Anon Coward thanks it was that..I don't know how I couldn't see it, don't know if worth it but if you want to answer the question I select it as the correct, maybe helps to always double check thing kind of things...